# Idiomatic HTML generation in PHP

Tags: php, html

In a separate question here on StackOverflow ([PHP library for HTML tag generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173367/php-library-for-html-tag-generation#comment14658520_11173367)) I asked if there is a popular or standard HTML tag library for PHP.

A couple of comments showed up questioning the purpose of such a library.

Here's a bit of code from the highly acclaimed book "PHP and MySQL Web Development 4th Edition" by Luke Welling and Laura Thomson:

```
echo "<td width = \"".$width."%\">
<a href=\"".$url."\">
<img src=\"s-logo.gif\" alt=\"".$name."\" border=\"0\" /></a>
<a href=\"".$url."\"><span class=\"menu\">".$name."</span></a>
</td>";
```

I thought all the escaping and concatenating looked a little messy, so I cooked up an [HTML generation library](https://gist.github.com/2980249). The above looks like this using the library:

```
return td(array('width' => $width . '%'),
    a(array('href' => $url),
        img(array('src' => 's-logo.gif', 'alt' => $name, 'border' => 0))),
    a(array('href' => $url), span(array('class' => 'menu'), $name)));
```

My question is (and keep in mind, I'm a php newb), what's the idiomatic way to write the above? Is there a cleaner way to write the book example?

Comment: mediawiki does something similar, have a look how I used it to make a select https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/extensions/AllTimeZones.git;a=blob;f=AllTimeZones.php;h=be501d159b606582947de737c4be994d170bc061;hb=HEAD#l190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **PHP heredoc syntax**

```
<?php

$width=10;
$url="www.google.com";
$name="stackoverflow";

echo <<<EOT
<td width = "$width">
<a href="$url">
<img src="s-logo.gif" alt="$name" border="0" /></a>
<a href="$url"><span class="menu">$name</span></a>
</td>
EOT;
?>
```

For more information refer [Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner - definitely, with `heredoc`:

```
echo <<<HTML
<td width="{$width}%">
<a href="{$url}"><img src="s-logo.gif" alt="{$name}" border="0" /></a>
<a href="{$url}"><span class="menu">{$name}</span></a>
</td>
HTML;
```